# Passing an array on Template Render

Tags: templating

I am trying to pass an array on template render like this:

```
public function actionConfirm()
{
   $variables['confirm'] = array(
      'name'   => 'Silvanus',
      'office' => 'OOTS',
    );
    $this->renderTemplate('confirm', $variables);
}
```

And output it in layout like this:

```
{%for variable in variables%}
  {{variable.name}}
  {{variable.office}}
```

This is just an example, mainly after client pays using paypal I get a payment Object that I want to pass it to the confirmation layout as per explanation above. I have tried it doesn't work.

Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do it with the setRouteVariables mathod on UrlManager, like this:

```
craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
    'variable' => array(
      'name' => 'silvanus',
      'office' => 'OOTS
    )
));

$this->renderTemplate('confirm');
```

Now you can access your variables like this in your template:

```
{{ variable.name }}
{{ variable.office }}
```

Check out the [documentation on Controllers](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers), there's an example.

EDIT:
The above method is how I've done it in the past, but I see now that the renderTemplate method also can be used. I think the problem is just how you access it in your templates, I think you should just do:

```
{{ confirm.name }}
{{ confirm.office }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much aelvan,the EDITED version of answer is what I was looking for.Cheers mate.

Comment: Can you explain the full code again please? Because I can't get it to work for me.